# Watson Studio Data connection

Tags: google-bigquery, watson-studio

I want to create a new connection to Google BigQuery and through the Data Connection in Watson Studio. I however cannot find the Database in the List. Can you please support? The ultimate objective is to get this data in Watson Analytics and do exploratory analysis.

Comment: I would love if Watson supported reading from BigQuery, but searching around the web doesn't surface any results.

Answer (score 0):

Support for Google BigQuery in Watson Studio and Watson Knowledge Catalog is now available. The current list of supported 3rd party services are as follows:

[image]